# Hibernate Restrictions: Object betweeen two DB.table.propertyName

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, restriction

This is the normal use of Hibernate's between constraint

```
Criterion critDate = Restrictions.between("fromDatePropName", model.getFromDate(), model.getToDate()) ;
```

But I want the constraint between `Object` with two or more `propertyName` in hibernate.

For ex: I want the Date `'2011-10-01'` between `tableName.fromDatePropName` and `tableName.toDatePropName`

This is how I want to do with one method:

Ex:

```
Criterion critDate = Restrictions.between(model.getDate(), "fromDatePropName", "toDatePropName") ;
```

Visual Ex:

Here is the SQL generated with:

```
Criterion critDate = Restrictions.between("fromDatePropName", model.getFromDate(), model.getToDate()) ;
Criterion critDate = Restrictions.between(  "toDatePropName", model.getFromDate(), model.getToDate()) ;

...
AND tableName.fromDatePropName  between DATE '2011-10-01' and DATE '2011-10-31' 
AND tableName.toDatePropName    between DATE '2011-10-01' and DATE '2011-10-31' 
...
```

But this is the SQL I want to generate:

```
Criterion critDate = Restrictions.between(model.getDate(), "fromDatePropName", "toDatePropName") ;

...
AND DATE'2011-10-01'  between tableName.fromDatePropName and tableName.toDatePropName
...
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Where do those properties come from? Are they properites of the entity you want to compare?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

`Restrictions.between("date", model.getFromDate(), model.getToDate())`

From the [`Restrictions.between()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#between%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) javadoc, the property name is the first argument, and is relative to the entity the Criteria is rooted to.

If you really want to specify a restriction such as requiring a property of the rooted entity being between two other properties of the same entity, you could use the [`Restrictions.geProperty()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#gtProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`Restrictions.leProperty()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#leProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods instead of `Restrictions.between()`.

```
Restrictions.geProperty("date", "fromDate")
```

and

```
Restrictions.leProperty("date", "toDate")
```